Error setting up dead-letter exchange for queues in RabbitMQ using Node.js: PRECONDITION_FAILED
I'm facing difficulties while trying to subscribe to a queue in RabbitMQ from my Node.js application. First, let me share the relevant code snippets from my application:
async function subscribeToQueue(
  channel,
  exchangeName,
  queuesNames,
  handleMessage
) {
  console.log("subscribe to queue")
  try {
    await channel?.assertExchange(exchangeName, "direct", {
      durable: true,
    });

    const deadQueueOptions = {
      durable: true,
    };
    console.log("dead queue antes de instanciada")

    await channel?.assertQueue("deadQueue", deadQueueOptions);
    console.log("dead queue instanciada")
    for (const queueName of queuesNames) {
      const mainQueueOptions = {
        durable: true,
        arguments: {
          "x-queue-type": "quorum",
          "x-max-retries": 5,
          "x-dead-letter-exchange": "dlx",
          "x-dead-letter-routing-key": "dlx",
        },
      };
      console.log("mainQueueOptions fijada")

      const q = await channel?.assertQueue(`${queueName}`, mainQueueOptions);
      console.log("main queue instanciada")

      await channel?.bindQueue(q.queue, exchangeName, `${queueName}`);

      await channel?.consume(
        queueName,
        async (message) => {
          if (message.content) {
            try {
              const event = await JSON.parse(message.content.toString());
              await handleMessage(event);
              channel.ack(message);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error al procesar el mensaje:", error);
              channel.nack(message);
            }
          }
        },
        { noAck: false }
      );

      console.log(`Se suscribió correctamente a la cola: ${queueName}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error en la suscripción a la cola: ", error);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  subscribeToQueue,
};


And here is the relevant configuration from RabbitMQ management:
Virtual Host | Name | Pattern | Apply to | Definition
/            | dlx  | .*      | all      | dead-letter-exchang: deadQueue
| dead-letter-routing-key: deadQueue
This error seems to be related to the configuration of queues in RabbitMQ, specifically with the 'x-dead-letter-exchange' property. I'm trying to assign a dead-letter queue to my queues, and when I instantiate the dead-letter queue, this error occurs. I've configured the dead-letter queue policy in a certain way in RabbitMQ management, and I'm attaching a screenshot of my configuration.
Could someone explain what this error means and how I can fix it in my Node.js application?
In my attempts to resolve this issue, I've reviewed the RabbitMQ documentation regarding dead-letter exchanges and queues. I've also experimented with different configurations for the dead-letter queue policy in RabbitMQ management. However, despite these efforts, I continue to encounter the 406 (PRECONDITION-FAILED) error when attempting to instantiate the dead-letter queue.

That error is because already exist a queue with the same name but with different condition (options) setted.
I dunno if there is a better way, but in my case, I have to delete the queue manually from the console and run the app again to create a fresh queue.
This happened every time I modify any queue options.
